# How to blend two background images, repeated and non-repeated one?

Tags: css, image, background, sass, background-image

I need to blend two background images with multiply blend mode, but the first image should not be repeated and the second image should be repeated, because it is a pattern.

How can I do it using SASS (CSS)?

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url('img1.jpg'),url('img2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

This is how most background-image-related properties work, including `background-size` and `background-position`; when multiple images are specified (comma-separated url list, as shown), you can list properties for each image. The orders will match up, meaning in our example, `img1.jpg` will not repeat, and `img2.jpg` will.